# Как поставить точку остановки в управляемом коде?

Tags: c#, отладка, clr, windbg

У меня есть простая программа, которую я хочу отладить:

```
class Program
{
    static void MyWrite()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("TEST!!!!!");
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("PRE");
        MyWrite();
        System.Console.WriteLine("POST");
    }
}
```

Допустим, я хочу поставить точку остановки в начало исполнения MyWrite используя Windbg. Для этого я выполняю следующие шаги:

1. Открываю windbg
2. Открываю ConsoleApplication1.exe файл
3. Выполняю команду `sxe ld:clr`
4. Выполняю команду `g`
5. Выполняю команду `.loadby sos clr`
6. Выполняю команду `!bpmd ConsoleApplication1.exe ConsoleApplication1.Program.MyWrite`

Последняя команда фейлится с сообщением

> c0000005 Exception in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\sos.bpmd debugger extension.
>         PC: 0a13b780  VA: 00000000  R/W: 0  Parameter: 00000000

Не понимаю, в чем ошибка.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Для работы `!bpmd` нужен `clrjit`, а на момент загрузки `clr` его скорее всего нет.
2. `.loadby sos clr` может глючить - криво загружать sos. Помогает `.unload` и еще один `.loadby sos clr`. Но указание прямого пути надежнее.
3. У вас класс объявлен без namespace (т.е. он просто `Program`, а не `ConsoleApplication1.Program`, а брекпойнт вы пытаетесь ставить так, как будто бы namespace у вас есть). Может быть на самом деле и есть, просто вы код не весь привели.

Рабочая последовательность:

```
sxe ld:clrjit
g
.load C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\sos.dll
!bpmd ConsoleApplication1.exe Program.MyWrite()
```

`.exe` и `()` в последней строке опциональны, без них тоже должно работать.

Вывод должен выглядеть вот так:

```
0:000>  !bpmd ConsoleApplication1.exe Program.MyWrite()
Found 1 methods in module 00f03fdc...
MethodDesc = 00f04d04
Adding pending breakpoints...
```

Если пишет просто

```
Adding pending breakpoints...
```

...значит вы не угадали с именем сборки, класса или метода.

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать. Кстати да, неймспейса у меня нет.

Comment: Да, все работает.